# Cuenta atrás cada x segundos

Tags: javascript

Necesito hacer una cuenta atrás a un numero cada 60 seg, por ejemplo, hay 200 coches disponibles y cada x seg se le reste -1 (199 coches disponibles). He estado probando pero no logro sacarlo...

Comment: Comparte el codigo de lo que has intentado

Comment: Debes mostrar el código que has intentado usar y decirnos cual fue el problema que encontraste, es importante que leas [ask], saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías usar la función [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) y hacer que le reste a una variable la cantidad de coches cada 1 segundo o 1000 milisegundos, que es la medida en que se expresa los intervalos y después si querés parar el intervalo podés usar [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval). Por ejemplo:

```js
// cantidad de coches
var coches = 200;
// 1 segundo expresado en milisegundos
var tiempo = 1000;
// genero el intervalo y lo guardo en una variable para que
// pueda parar el intervalo, en caso de necesitarlo
var intervalo = window.setInterval(function() {
  // acá ejecuto lo que quiera hacer
  console.log(coches);
  // resto un coche
  coches--;
  
  // compruebo que llegue a 0
  if (coches === 0) {
    // cancelo en intervalo
    window.clearInterval(intervalo);
  }
}, tiempo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo que tu quieres seria algo como esto:

```js
var coches = 2000

console.log(coches)

window.setInterval(function(){
   coches-- //restar de la variable coches
   console.log(coches)

}, 1000) // tiempo en milisegundo
```